# IndexedDB syncronism issue when creating parallel stores in the same db

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb

Whenever I try to archieve creating diffrent stores in the same database at the same time only one of them is created. Is there a way to resolve this syncronism issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already been able to solve this issue but I'll clarify what I ment in case it might help someone else. I have a GridView component which is mapped multiple times. This component saves the columns, how they are aranged and their specific behaviors to be stored inside indexedDB. The issue I had was that I used a function that created a Db named after the page and the stores (one for each GridView inside the same DB). In order to create all the stores at the same time (in this case I had to create 9 of them) I had to trigger a version change for each of the new stores in order to be able to persist the information. Inside the function I searched for the Db actual version and added 1 to trigger the version change event. The problem has that because they where searching the version synchronously inside this function all of the itterations were getting the same version and the result would be that only the first store was beeing created because only the first iteration of the map would trigger a version change. In order to resolve this issue I used index prop iside the map function and passed it as an order prop to my GridView component. Then instead of triggering the version change (version+1) inside the function I triggered by using version+order, this way all the stores where being created because it assures that all the versions were going to be higher than the previous ones.

I'll give some code to maybe help the explanation.

This is the map:

```
{status.map((status, index) => {
   return (
     <GridView
        pageName={"Page"} // DB Name
        gridName={status} // Store Name
        order={index + 1} // index + 1 so that the order is never 0
        //all the other props...
     />
   );
})}
```

Inside the GridView component I have a function that triggers on first render to search for the store inside the db and if there is no information inside creates and then fills the store with the information needed. This the function:

/**
*

- @param {String} DB_NAME
- @param {String} STORE_NAME
- @param {String} keyPath
- @param {Int} order
- @param {Object/Array} info
- @returns {Object}: resolve: {success,message,storeInfo), reject:{error, message}

```
*/
    const createAndPopulateStore = (
    DB_NAME,
    STORE_NAME,
    keyPath,
    order = 1,
    info
  ) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const request = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME);

      request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        let database = e.target.result;
        let version = parseInt(database.version);
        database.close();
        //This was the critical part in order to create multiple stores at the same time.
        let secondRequest = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, version + order); 
        secondRequest.onupgradeneeded = (e) => {
          let database = e.target.result;
          //Early return if the store already exist.
          if (database.objectStoreNames.contains(STORE_NAME)) {
            reject({
              success: false,
              message: `There is already a store named: ${STORE_NAME} created in the database: ${DB_NAME}`,
            });
            return;
          }

          let objectStore = database.createObjectStore(STORE_NAME, { keyPath });
          if (info) {
            // Populates the store within the db named after the gridName prop with the indexedColumns array.
            if (Array.isArray(info)) {
              info.map((item) => objectStore.put(item));
            } else {
              Object.entries(info).map((item) => objectStore.put(item));
            }
          }
        };
        secondRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
          resolve({
            success: true,
            message: `Store: ${STORE_NAME}, created successfully.`,
            storeInfo: info ?? {},
          });
          let database = e.target.result;
          database.close();
        };
      };
    });
  };
```

I hope this will help! Fell free to ask any questions regarding this issue and I'll try to answer them as soon as I can.